# Xamarin Android Google Places Api AutoComplete broken

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, google-places-api

I'm trying to get the basic autocomplete functionality from [Google's Places Api](https://developers.google.com/places/android/autocomplete) working with Xamarin Android.

I'm using version 25.0.0.0 of Xamarin's [Google Play Services - Location](http://components.xamarin.com/view/googleplayservices)  lib.

I've managed to get to the point of returning results of a query while following [this example code](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/blob/master/PlaceComplete/Application/src/main/java/com/example/google/playservices/placecomplete/PlaceAutocompleteAdapter.java)

This is the Fragment I'm using to test the code

```
public class PlaceAutocomplete: BaseFragment, IGoogleApiClientOnConnectionFailedListener {
    IGoogleApiClient client;
    public override void OnCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        base.OnCreate( savedInstanceState );
        client = new GoogleApiClientBuilder( Activity )
                                            .EnableAutoManage( Activity as BaseFragmentActivity, 0, this )
                                            .AddOnConnectionFailedListener( OnConnectionFailed )
                                            .AddApi( Places.GEO_DATA_API )
                                            .Build();
    }

    public override View OnCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        Places.GeoDataApi.GetAutocompletePredictions( client, "cul",
        new LatLngBounds( new LatLng( 33.515071, -118.796427 ), new LatLng( 34.435985, -117.127371 ) ), null )
        .SetResultCallback<AutocompletePredictionBuffer>( AutocompleteResult );

        return base.OnCreateView( inflater, container, savedInstanceState );
    }

    public void AutocompleteResult( AutocompletePredictionBuffer buffer ) {

        if( !buffer.Status.IsSuccess ) {
            Toast.MakeText( Activity, buffer.Status.StatusMessage, ToastLength.Long ).Show();
            return;
        }

        var a = new List<IAutocompletePrediction>();
        for( var i = 0; i < buffer.Count; i++ ) {
            var item = buffer.Get( i );
            if( item is IAutocompletePrediction ) {
                a.Add( (IAutocompletePrediction) item );
            } else {
                 //all the results go in here
            }
        }

        Toast.MakeText( Activity, a.Count.ToString(), ToastLength.Long ).Show();
    }

    public void OnConnectionFailed( ConnectionResult result ) {

    }
}
```

There are 5 returned results from *GetAutocompletePredictions* method but all of them of type named **com.google.android.gms.location.places.internal.zzb**, cannot be cast to IAutocompletePrediction and I did not find any way to use them.

Did I do something wrong or this part of Xamarin's Google Play library is not fully implemented?

Comment: if your requirement is only autocomplete from place api then this might be helpful to you, download using REST request http://appliedcodelog.blogspot.in/2015/05/google-place-api-with-autocomplete-in.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit - New Information**

This is not a bug. The **IAutocompletePrediction** is not currently implemented by Xamarin so you must cast it like this

```
item.JavaCast<IAutocompletePrediction>()
```

in order to use it.

**Older informaton**

I've talked to Xamarin Support and they've confirmed that this is a bug.

More info on the bug fix can be found here https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=31878

Answer (score 0):

As of

Xamarin 4.0.0.1717 /

Xamarin.Android 6.0.0.35 /

Xamarin Google Play Services Location component v 27.0.0.0

, it seems there's been a bit of work in this space.
The IEnumerable interface now provides a way to get a typed response, and the following snippet (replacing part of AutocompleteResult) works:

```
var a = new List<IAutocompletePrediction>();
String t = "";
foreach (IAutocompletePrediction x in buffer)
{
    a.Add(x);
    t += "\n" + x.GetFullTextFormatted(new StyleSpan(TypefaceStyle.Normal)).ToString();
}

Toast.MakeText(Activity, t /* a.Count.ToString() */, ToastLength.Long).Show();
```